# Find battery wear in 16.04

Tags: power-management, laptop, indicator, battery

My laptop battery started to behave strangely since some days. Without showing low battery, it will from around 30 % go to 6 % ( critical battery ). And, at times, will shutdown even if I turn on the main power. Since today, it is stuck at 6 % all the time. I even kept the laptop off and charging for an hour to fix it.  Now after a half the day at 6%, it now shows 5% all the time. Sometime before there was some pulling of power cable and the cable got detached from power socket of the laptop. And, this threw a critical battery warning.

I have tried a command I found from Google to check the battery status ( results below ). I could only think of a very high percentage of battery wear. But the command I run didn't show anything that indicates the same. Is there any way that I can check the battery wear in 16.04 ?

```
 $ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0  
    native-path:          BAT0   vendor:               Sanyo   model:   
    DELL 4YRJH53   serial:               308   power supply:         yes
    updated:              Tue 10 Oct 2017 03:36:40 PM IST (50 seconds
    ago)   has history:          yes   has statistics:       yes  
    battery
        present:             yes
        rechargeable:        yes
        state:               charging
        warning-level:       none
        energy:              0.918 Wh
        energy-empty:        0 Wh
        energy-full:         15.39 Wh
        energy-full-design:  15.39 Wh
        energy-rate:         0.0108 W
        voltage:             11.506 V
        percentage:          5%
        capacity:            100%
        technology:          lithium-ion
        icon-name:          'battery-caution-charging-symbolic'
```

Update :

Power Statistics show batter wear as Nil. Considering I am using this battery since over a year, I don't know whether I should believe it

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the charger or charger cable isn't broken?

Comment: @THelper It must be working fine. Because I can use with the power ON ( even though the battery stays at 5% ).